# New type of the input layer in MLP Neural Network

Tags: matlab, neural-network, layer

I am using MATLAB for implementation of MLP Neural Network. As i found in the most cases and examples, all input layer variables are one-dimensional. For example, if we have 5 input layers (attributes), they can be as:

```
[ Input ]    [Target]
1 2 3 5 6       1
3 4 6 1 3       2
5 6 1 1 6       1
...
...
1 1 4 1 5       1
```

And target is also one-dimensional for each sample in the last column. In my case, i am going to define 3-dimensional input pattern for each input neuron such as:

```
    [----------- Input ------------]      [Target]
[1 2 3] [2 3 4] [3 4 4] [5 3 1] [6 5 6]       1
[5 5 5] [5 4 1] [1 2 2] [1 1 2] [4 2 2]       2
...
...
[3 4 5] [5 1 1] [3 3 2] [4 6 5] [4 5 2]       2
```

Is it possible in the MLP? Or should i convert all the 3-dimensional data into one-dimensional? such as by Variance.

I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Is the input for each sample a 3D object of some type?  The typical thing to do with multi-dimensional object such as images is to just turn them in to a vector representing the input.

Comment: Yes. My input data is 3D format for each input neuron. Your suggestion is a vector representation, how is it possible? for example, for input [1 2 3], i should apply 123? or present in bit each number? such as [001 010 011]?

Comment: You can input whatever values you want as the input of your network.  Your input vector should just be the concatenation of all of your input features.  If you input is just 3 numbers per sample then you should have 3 input neurons, one for each value.